# Wrong rotation of images using Android camera2 API in Google's example code?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have tried writing my own code for accessing camera via the camera2 API on Android instead of using the [Google's example](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic). On one hand, I've wasted way too much time understanding what exactly is going on, but on the other hand, I have noticed something quite weird:

I want the camera to produce vertical images. However, despite the fact that the `ImageReader` is initialized with height larger than width, the Image that I get in the `onCaptureCompleted` has the same size, except it is rotated 90 degrees. I was struggling trying to understand my mistake, so I went exploring Google's code. And what I have found is that their images are rotated 90 degrees as well! They compensate for that by setting a `JPEG_ORIENTATION` key in the `CaptureRequestBuilder` (if you comment that single line, the images that get saved will be rotated). This is unrelated to device orientation - in my case, screen rotation is disabled for the app entirely.

The problem is that for the purposes of the app I am making I need a non-compressed precise data from camera, so since JPEG a) compresses images b) with losses, I cannot use it. Instead I use the YUV_420_888 format which I later convert to a `Bitmap`. But while the `JPEG_ORIENTATION` flag can fix the orientation for JPEG images, it seems to do nothing for YUV ones. So how do I get the images to be correctly rotated?

One obvious solution is to rotate the resulting `Bitmap`, but I'm unsure what angle should I rotate it by on different devices. And more importantly, what causes such strange behavior?

*Update:* rotating the Bitmap and scaling it to proper size takes way too much time for the preview (the context is as follows: I need both high-res images from camera to process and a downscaled version of these same images in preview. Let's just say I'm making something similar to QR code recognition). I have even tried using RenderScripts to manipulate the image efficiently, but this is still too long. Also, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53163640/10908201) that when I set multiple output surfaces simultaneously, the same resolution will be used for all of them, which is quite bad for me.

Comment: Note that [`JPEG_ORIENTATION=90`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#JPEG_ORIENTATION) results in landscape image (with an Exif hint) on most devices, but on some devices it may produce a true portrait image.

Comment: Usually, Jpeg lossy compression is not a problem because the resolution available in Jpeg is much higher than that you can get for YUV. So, even with lossy compression you get much more detail in Jpeg. But this depends on device, too.

Comment: You can try [libyuv](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/) to convert YUV to RGB while applying rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Android stores every image, no matter if it is taken in landscape or in portrait, in landscape mode. It also stores metadata that tells you if the image should be displayed in portrait or landscape.

If you don'r turn the image according to the metadata, you will end up with every image in landscape. I had that problem too (but I wanted compression so my solution doesn't work for you).

You need to read the metadata and turn it accordingly.
I hope this helps at least a bit.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that thing about landscape mode. Although I cant find how to extract meta from an `Image` object. Maybe anyone can help with that?

Comment: Look for something like : 
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);